# Laravel which filter is faster

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel, basic-authentication

I used this API as a starter pack:

https://github.com/akuzemchak/laracon-todo-api

The filter for the basic auth looked like this:

```
Route::filter('api.auth', function()
{
    if (!Request::getUser())
    {
        App::abort(401, 'A valid API key is required');
    }
    $user = User::where('api_key', '=', Request::getUser())->first();
    if (!$user)
    {
        App::abort(401);
    }
    Auth::login($user);
});
```

Which would authenticate a user like: curl -u "youruserapikeygoeshere:whatever" http://localapidomain.dev/v1/lists

But wont it be slow to check the api key against the varchar field on the DB?

I modified my filter so that I send the users id as username then the password as the api key.

Then my query will select the user from the primary key and then check if the API key match.

Coz if I understand it right it will be faster to make a lookup query against a primary key instead of " WHERE api_key = key "

```
Route::filter('api.auth', function()
{
    if (!Request::getUser())
    {
        App::abort(401, 'A valid user ID and API key is required');
    }

    $user = User::where('user_id', '=', Request::getUser())->first(['api_key']);

    if (!$user)
    {
        App::abort(401);
    }

    if ($user->api_key == Request::getPassword())
    {
        Auth::login($user);
    }
    else
    {
        App::abort(401);
    }
});
```

So is my second filter better/faster?

Comment: If you want a MySQL opinion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the SELECTs, and the size of the table.

Comment: @RickJames is it not always faster to do a look up on a primary key instead of a varchar eg: "WHERE something = 34_dsFFJsjd"
As for now a do a lookup on the primary key, then check if that rows api column matches the given one eg: $data->api_key = "34_dsFFJsjd"

Comment: It all depends on the indexes, hence the desire to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (I don't speak `laravel`, just SQL.)